# I am looking to find a partial match between two arrays

Tags: excel, text, matching, partial

I'm trying bring about a partial match result based on two arrays.  One array has paragraphs that might contain words from the second array.  If there is a match to one of the words in the second array, then the word (or words) should appear in the "result" column (column B in the example below.  The matching words have at least the first four letter matching or else there will be too many matches.  The first image is the initial state table.  the one below that is the resulting table.

Initial State

[image]

Resulting state

[image]

Right now, I am using a formula that results in too many matches.  I'm hoping there's one that will work for me.

```excel-formula
=TEXTJOIN("; ",,FILTER($C$2:$C$212,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(LEFT($C$2:$C$212,4),A2))))
```

Comment: Give us data to copy -too lazy to type it for you. But I would be testing FIND() with IF()

Comment: I would gladly give you a spreadsheet via attachment, but don't see an option for this.  is it somewhere on the website that I've missed?

Comment: What you seem to have missed is my answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

So, try this:

[image]

To save you typing:

```
MID(A1,MAX(IFERROR(FIND($G$1:$G$3,A1,1),0)),FIND(" ",A1,MAX(IFERROR(FIND($G$1:$G$3,A1,1),0))+1)-MAX(IFERROR(FIND($G$1:$G$3,A1,1),0)))
```